# MOSS 2007 Email Alerts to Google Apps

Tags: 2007, email, active-directory

We recently migrated to Google Apps, and after removing Exchange 2010 from our domain we no longer get our SharePoint alerts. Through some digging I believe this is because Exchange removes the email attributes from user objects in Active Directory.

So I tried manually adding my email address to my AD User General attribute "E-mail". After making the change and replicating AD, I synced the changes to MOSS by running: stsadm -o sync -synctiming M:5 & stsadm -o sync -sweeptiming M:5. Which both completed successfully, however, I still have no email address set in SharePoint, and can not use alerts.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Randomly 3 days later email alerts are working... only for users I made the changes for:

- update AD user object to include email address
- run stsadm -o sync -synctiming M:5
- run stsadm -o sync -sweeptiming M:5.